# 2 unknowns in 2 interdependent non-linear equations

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-point-iteration

Given $C_1$, $C_2$ and $\lambda_i$ for $1 \le i \le N$, I am looking for unknown $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ in the following system:

\begin{array}{c,c}
\sum_{i=1}^N P_{i}(\tau_1,\tau_2) = C_1 & (1)\\ \\
\sum_{i=1}^N Q_{i}(\tau_1,\tau_2) = C_2 & (2)\\ \\
\end{array}
in which

\begin{array}{c,c}
P_{i}(\tau_1,\tau_2)  = \Big(Q_{i}(\tau_1,\tau_2)\big(1 - exp(-\lambda_i\tau_1)\big)\Big)/\Big(exp(-\lambda_i\tau_1) + Q_{i}(\tau_1,\tau_2)\big(1-exp(-\lambda_i\tau_1)\big)\Big) & (3)\\ \\
Q_{i}(\tau_1,\tau_2)  = 1 - exp\Big(-\lambda_i\big(1-P_{i}(\tau_1,\tau_2)\big)\tau_2\Big) & (4)\\ \\
\lambda_i > \lambda_j \quad \forall i,j \quad i < j \quad 1 \le i,j \le N & (5)
\end{array}
Since $Q_{i}(\tau_1,\tau_2)$ and $P_{i}(\tau_1,\tau_2)$ are interdependent, I guess a fixed-point iterative procedure is required.

Could someone please help me with a suggestion or hint to help me find $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To make things simpler, consider that you have to solve $$F(x,y)=0$$ $$G(x,y)=0$$ and you need "good" starting values for $x_0$ and $y_0$.

Consider $$\Phi(x,y)=F^2(x,y)+G^2(x,y)$$ which would be $0$ at solution.

So, make a $2D$ grid computing $\Phi(x,y)$ for different values of $x,y$; look for which pair you get the minimum value of $\Phi(x,y)$ and start from this point.

Comment: thanks for your comment @claude-leibovici. Well, could you please explain how I can define F and G in your answer.
The issue I am facing nowt is that I cannot come up with any value for P and Q in my question for any arbitrary pair of $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$.

Comment: Don't try to be more explicit. Just use $$F=\sum_{i=1}^N P_{i}(\tau_1,\tau_2) - C_1$$ $$G=\sum_{i=1}^N Q_{i}(\tau_1,\tau_2) - C_2$$

Comment: I do not know if I got it right or not. Please correct me if I am wrong.

So, having F and G as 2D functions of $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$, I try different values of $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ to calculate $\Phi$. Meanwhile, Since $P_i$ and $Q_i$ are used in F and G, I can use iterative methods to calculate $P_i$ and $Q_i$ based on values of $\tau_1$  and $\tau_2$.

Then, what would be the next step after finding $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$ that minimises $\Phi$, ?

Comment: Newton-Raphson for the two variables or better a minimizer hoping to get $\Phi=0$